# Prove for all $x$ there exists a $y$ such that $x + y = 1$ within the domain of all real numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification

So we can simplify $x + y = 1$ to  $y = 1 -x$ and no matter what value of $x$, the value of $y$ will always be $-x + 1$.

Is that an ample proof? It just seems too easy.

Comment: Nope.  That's good enough.  Seems like the exercise is one of developing proof writing style.  But yeah.  For any $x \in \mathbb R $ there is a $y =1-x $ so that $x+y =x +(1-x)=1$.  That's all there is to it.  The rest is style points.

Comment: What prerequisites do you have? What is known about $\mathbb R$?

Comment: These two answers are both excellent and perfectly correct.  But IMO they are preposterously over done.  The prove is a single line: for all real x there is a real y = 1-x so x+y = 1.  That's it.  Now, I suppose the actual question could be what axioms and definitions do we know about the real numbers so that we can say for certainty that y=1-x always exists and is a legitimate well defined number, and how do we know x+(1-x)=1.  But to answer those (or even to know if we *should* answer those) we need to know the context of what class this was and want context have the reals been introduced.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that
$$
x+y=1\iff y=1-x
$$
can be proven this way.

$(\Longrightarrow)$ Suppose $x+y=1$. Then
$$
-x+(x+y)=-x+1
$$
By associativity of addition (in $\mathbb{R}$), $-x+(x+y)=(-x+x)+y$. By definition of $-x$ as the additive inverse of $x$, we have$-x+x=0$. Hence $(-x+x)+y=0+y$. Since $0$ is the additive neutral element, we have $0+y=y$. Hence
$$
y=-x+1
$$
By commutativity of the addition, $-x+1=1+(-x)$. The notation $1-x$ means $1+(-x)$, so $-x+1=1-x$.

All in all, we have $y=1-x$.

$(­\Longleftarrow)$ A similar argument works.

**Note 1:** Most of the time we take many properties of $\mathbb{R}$ for granted, namely the properties of a [complete ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#.22The_complete_ordered_field.22). One example of a property we often take for granted (that we take as an axiom) is that the addition is associative.

However, it is possible to take more general axioms and deduce those properties from them. The [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) are sufficient to prove every property for $\mathbb{N}$ and from $\mathbb{N}$ we may *construct* rigorously the number systems $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ and *prove* the properties as consequences of the Peano axioms (which are, in a sense, more minimal).

More general axioms than those of Peano would be axioms for a set theory, for example the axioms of the [Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory). It is interesting that from the axioms of ZF we can actually *deduce* the Peano axioms and prove the properties of a complete ordered field that we wish $\mathbb{R}$ would have.

**Note 2:** Obviously all those steps are rarely shown. But if you're interested in an axiomatic approach, then it can't be bad to be aware of what's going on.

---

If all you want to do is prove that for all $x$ there exists a $y$ such that $x+y=1$, then you can proceed like this.

Fix $x$. Let $y:=-x+1$ (we take $y$ to be this and, as user @Pragnya Jha mentioned in the comments, $-x+1$ *is* a real number). Then
\begin{align}
x+y&=x+(-x+1)&&\text{by def of }y\\
&=(x+(-x))+1&&\text{by associativity of }+\\
&=0+1&&\text{by def of }-x\\
&=1&&\text{neutral property of }0
\end{align}

Hence we have exhibited a $y$ that works. This completes the proof.

Comment: Up voted your answer, however, you also need to show that $-x+1 \in R$, if $x \in R$. It is, of course, trivial because R is an ordered field, as you already stated.

Comment: @Pragnya Jha If you want to prove that, you have to define the addition of real numbers. I thought going into Dedekind cuts or rational Cauchy sequences wasn't really necessary here. If you object that I should have proven that, then you must object that I should have proved that addition is associative, that it is commutative, etc. But your point is valuable. I'll add it to my answer, thanks.

Comment: Or you can just assume R to be an ordered field and then, you only need to add one more line to your proof.  Ah well, just saw your edit.

Comment: @Pragnya Jha My answer assumes that $\mathbb{R}$ is a complete ordered field, as is usual in many real analysis textbooks. There's no point in not assuming that here.

Comment: Obviously when trying to prove that $(\mathbb R, +)$ is a group you can't use the fact that $(\mathbb R, +, \cdot)$ is an ordered field. How do you know there's such thing as $-y$? You're going to have to use the definition of $\mathbb R$ and work with nested intervals of rational numbers.

Comment: @ThomasR I don't understand the point you're trying to make. I made it very clear in my answer that I assumed that we know $\mathbb{R}$ is a complete ordered field. I said that those properties can be proved by more general axioms (ZF) only for the OP's mathematical interest.

Comment: "I assumed that we know $\mathbb R$" - then your proof is a tautology. You might as well assume that for all $x$, there exists $y$ such that $x+y=1$. In other words: to prove A, you cannot use something that is derived from A.

Comment: @ThomasR If what we wanted to prove was that for all $x$ there is a $y$ such that $x+y=0$ then I would agree with you. I see no circularity in the argument I gave. The statement to prove is not part of the definition of a field and is not used to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is a field. It is a consequence of it, as I showed. So please explain your point.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>**Note** To avoid confusion, I'm using round parentheses to denote sequences, and square brackets for grouping.</sub>

---

We prove the following:

1. $(\mathbb R, +)$ is a group
2. For every group $(G, \circ)$ and for every $a,b\in G$, there is $y\in G$ such that $a\circ y = b$.

Then the claim follows with $G=\mathbb R, \circ = +, a=x, b=1$.

Proof:

2. Let $a,b\in G$. Since $G$ is a group, there is an inverse Element $a^-$ such that $a\circ a^- = a^-\circ a = 0$. Let $y:=a^-\circ b$. Then $a\circ y = a\circ[a^-\circ b]=[a\circ a^-]\circ b = 0\circ b = b$.

1. This is the hard part. The set $\mathbb R$ is defined as the set of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb Q$, so:

   $$
       \mathbb R := \left\{(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}:a_n\in\mathbb Q,\forall\epsilon>0\exists N\in\mathbb N:\left|a_n-a_m\right|<\epsilon\text{ for }n,m > N\right\}/\sim
    $$

   with $$(a_n)\sim(b_n):\Leftrightarrow\left|a_n-b_n\right|\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}\longrightarrow0$$

   and the addition defined as $(a_n)+(b_n):=(a_n+b_n)$. [It must be proven that this is well-defined, which you probably have done already.]

   Sloppily speaking, *everything in $\mathbb R$ is just a sequence of rational numbers, and addition happens member by member*.

   Now, to prove that $(\mathbb R, +)$ is a group, we must show

   1. $a+[b+c] = [a+b]+c$ for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$, and
   2. $\color{red}{\text{For all } x \in \mathbb R\text{ there is }h\in\mathbb R\text{ such that }x+h=h+x=0}$. We write $-x$ to denote this element.

   It is very important to understand that you cannot blindly assume that $-x$ exists, just because you can write it down. The notation "$-x$" means: "This is an element that when added to $x$, yields the sum $0$". Again, **it must be proven that this exists**.

   Now, to prove the above points, write $a=(a_n), b=(b_n), c=(c_n), x=(x_n)$. Then, $$a+[b+c] =\\ (a_n)+[(b_n)+(c_n)] =\\ (a_n)+(b_n+c_n) =\\ (a_n+[b_n+c_n]) =\\([a_n+b_n]+c_n)=\\ (a_n+b_n)+(c_n) =\\ [(a_n)+(b_n)]+(c_n) =\\ [a+b]+c$$

   Remember that $a_n, b_n, c_n\in\mathbb Q$, so the associativity from $\mathbb Q$ can be used here.

   Likewise let $h:=(-x_n)$. We know that $-x_n\in\mathbb Q$ exist. Now,

$$x+h = (x_n)+(-x_n) = (x_n+[-x_n]) = (0) = 0$$

and

$$h+x = (-x_n)+(x_n) = (-x_n+x_n) = (0) = 0$$
$\square$

The basic idea here is to use the properties of $\mathbb Q$, which translate naturally to $\mathbb R$ via the members of the Cauchy sequences.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume $\mathbb R$ is a field the OP'S argument is sufficient:

For all $x \in \mathbb R$ there is a number $y=1 + (-x) $ and $x +y = x + [1+(-x)] =[x+(-x)]+1=0+1=1$

(i.e.  for all elements $x $ there is an additive inverse (-x) so that $x+(-x)=0$ and that there exists and additive identity so that $a+0=0+a $ for all $a $, and that $1$, the multiplicative identity, exist, and "$+$" is a binary operation so $a+b $ is a real number for all $a,b$)

So perhaps the exercise boils down to proving $\mathbb R $ is a field.  Or maybe not.

This does come down to, just what class is this for, and what introduction of the reals has the student had at this point in the class.

Somehow, I doubt the idea of this exercise is actually to define and elucidate the properties of the reals.  But if it is and that single line proof is not enough, perhaps we should be asking the OP to clarify, how the Reals have been introduced so far before going into such excruciating detail which is most likely overkill.

(Although, I have to admit the other answers do do the details very well.)